# Как в шаблоне Django вывести обрезанный текст без js?

Tags: python, django

Может быть, можно в модели сделать поле, которое наследовало бы значение (текст) от нужного поля, и обрезало до нужного размера?

Желательно, конечно, вывести без создания нового поля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть встроенные фильтры в django templates

`{{ value|truncatechars:9 }}` - если нужно обрезать переменную value до 9 символов

Также есть

`{{ value|truncatechars_html:9 }}` - если в value лежит html

`{{ value| truncatewords:2 }}` - обрезка до 2 слов

`{{ value| truncatewords_html:2 }}` - обрезка до 2 слов, если в value лежит html

Во всех случаях, если строка будет обрезана, будет добавлено "..." в конце.

[Ссылка на официальную документацию.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)